# Is color management used on Windows desktop background?

Tags: windows-10, desktop, color-profiles

On my Windows 10 system, I color calibrated my monitor and chose a neutral gray [180,180,180] solid color for the Windows desktop background, but the background appears to have a blue tint. This makes me think that Windows 10 does *not* perform color management on the desktop background color, as seems to be the case [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-winpc/windows-10-still-does-not-support-icc-profiles-in/587d46d2-73a9-4593-8158-cfad503088e6). Can you confirm this?

Comment: What image type are you using, with what embedded profile? The first answer [MS tagged] says use png with monitor profile. Windows has always been bad for screen colour & still can't do dual monitors properly even for pro apps, which is why traditionally Mac has owned the 'DTP' market.

Comment: hmmm... re-reading that, it looks like profiles are ignored even for png, they just don't suffer extra compression artefacts. Have to export with your correct LUT, so ignoring it == 'correct'. Yup, that's bad.

Comment: Sorry, my original question was unclear: I am actually looking that the color of the Windows desktop background, rather than any image, and it has a blue tint on my calibrated monitor.

Comment: I didn't even know you could set a colour rather than image. My knowledge kind of ends at "Windows is lousy at colour management, that's why I use a Mac"... sorry :/

Comment: I know color profiles affect the background image on Windows 7...so I would *assume* this has continued on into 10.

Comment: Found a video with the idea of using a purposely bad color profile to make it obvious what applications are doing color management, http://www.craigstocksarts.com/tutorials.html , search for 'How Windows Uses Monitor Profiles'. After the bad profile was set, I opened an image that didn't have an embedded ICC profile in different applications.  Here are the applications that are using the display color profile: Photoshop, Photo Viewer. Here are the applications that are ignoring the display color profile: Windows Desktop when I set an image as the background, Paint, and Gimp (!).

Comment: Also PowerPoint is not color managed, by the same bad profile test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO, it is not. But it should as everything which has no tag is in sRGB color (wide gamut monitors and Amoled displays then should manage it to correct it). That is how it works on macOS and iOS for desktop background. But Microsoft is trying to do it better, for example they now change the color profile immediately or so for color aware apps.
Do you know that jpeg background is being compressed even more by windows? Google it. One can set it to no compression, though.
Also you should understand that only one smartphone on Android now supports color managment -- galaxy s10 on natural profile and it is not supported in all apps really, while iOS had it long ago. That means that you cannot use HDR content really on Android because BT.2020 is converted to BT.709 (sRGB), while it should be converted to DCI-P3 color gamut which is between them! Really bad.

P.S. Actually the last thing is bypassed in many apps as many Samsung phones and tablets force DCI-P3 accurate profile when app toggles HDR support. And then if the app rightly converts gamut to DCI-P3 everything's good. (MX player, Netflix, VLC, Youtube all support it, though some much better than others.)